# Tkinter: update label's value by pressing a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to update label's value every time when a particular button is pressed. But root.update() doesn't work, moreover, I've failed to find any information how to update label or at least entire gui form to get new values! So, can anybody help with this?
Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import decimal

# random numbers
random1 = decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(-155, 548))/100
random2 = decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(-155, 548))/100


root = Tk()
root.title("Cheking numbers")
root.geometry("640x480")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)


# creating click event function
def ResultFunction():
    if random1 - random2 > 1.30:
        ResultLabel.configure(text='Result:' + str(random1 - random2))
    elif random1 < - 0.80 and random2 > -0.80:
        ResultLabel.configure(text='Result:' + str(random1))
    elif random1 > - 0.80 and random2 < -1.30:
        ResultLabel.configure(text='Result:' + str(random2))
    elif random1 < -0.80 and random2 < -1.30 and random1 < random2:
        ResultLabel.configure(text='Result:' + str(random1))
    elif random1 < -0.80 and random2 < -1.30 and random1 < random2:
        ResultLabel.configure(text='Result:' + str(random2))
    else:
        ResultLabel.configure(text='Result: 0')


# creating function for refreshing labels
def RefreshLabels():
    root.update()


# Labels
Number1Label = Label(root, text=str(random1), font='georgia 20')
Number1Label.pack()


Number2Label = Label(root, text=str(random2), font='georgia 20')
Number2Label.pack()


ResultLabel = Label(root, text='Result:', font='georgia 20')
ResultLabel.pack()


# Buttons
ResultButton = Button(root, text='Result', width=5, height=1, bg='white', fg='green', font='georgia 20', command=ResultFunction)
ResultButton.pack()


NextButton = Button(root, text='Next', width=6, height=1, bg='white', fg='green', font='georgia 20', command=RefreshLabels)
NextButton.pack()



mainloop()
```

Comment: `root.update()` allows the GUI to visually reflect changes in state, in the absence of a running mainloop (which isn't a situation you're facing); a typical use would be to show a moving progress bar during a long-running task that blocks the mainloop.  It does nothing for you, because you didn't change the state of anything, and have a working mainloop anyway.  You're on the right track with `ResultFunction()`, however it always sets the label to exactly the same text, because you're still using the same two random numbers that were generated when the program was initially ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ResultLabel is getting updated each time you click the ResultButton, but nothing appears to happen because the same random values get used every time. So you need to generate a new pair of random numbers each time.

I've simplified your program a bit, and changed the names to conform to the PEP-0008 style guide. I've also replaced the dreadful "star" import with something more sensible.

You don't need high precision decimal numbers for this task, simple float numbers are sufficient.

In your ResultFunction the last two `elif` clauses have the exact same condition. I assume that's a typo, so I changed the second one to what I think you wanted. ;)

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Checking numbers")
root.geometry("320x200")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

def show_result():
    random1 = random.randrange(-155, 548) / 100
    random2 = random.randrange(-155, 548) / 100

    number1_label.configure(text=str(random1))
    number2_label.configure(text=str(random2))

    if random1 - random2 > 1.30:
        v = random1 - random2
    elif random1 < -0.80 < random2:
        v = random1
    elif random1 > -0.80 and random2 < -1.30:
        v = random2
    elif random1 < -0.80 and random2 < -1.30 and random1 < random2:
        v = random1
    elif random1 < -0.80 and random2 < -1.30 and random2 < random1:
        v = random2
    else:
        v = 0.0

    result_label.configure(text='Result: {:.2f}'.format(v))

font = 'georgia 20'

# Labels
number1_label = tk.Label(root, text='', font=font)
number1_label.pack()

number2_label = tk.Label(root, text='', font=font)
number2_label.pack()

result_label = tk.Label(root, text='', font=font)
result_label.pack()

# Buttons
result_button = tk.Button(root, text='Result', width=5, height=1, 
    bg='white', fg='green', font=font, command=show_result)
result_button.pack()

# Initialize
show_result()

root.mainloop()
```

---

This version has two buttons. The 'Next' button generates & displays a new pair of random numbers, it also clears the 'Result' label. The 'Result' button performs the calculation & displays the result.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Checking numbers")
root.geometry("320x240")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

random1 = random2 = 0

# 'Next' button callback
def do_randoms():
    global random1, random2
    random1 = random.randrange(-155, 548) / 100
    random2 = random.randrange(-155, 548) / 100

    number1_label.configure(text=str(random1))
    number2_label.configure(text=str(random2))
    result_label.configure(text='Result:') 

# 'Result' button callback
def show_result():
    global random1, random2

    if random1 - random2 > 1.30:
        v = random1 - random2
    elif random1 < -0.80 < random2:
        v = random1
    elif random1 > -0.80 and random2 < -1.30:
        v = random2
    elif random1 < -0.80 and random2 < -1.30 and random1 < random2:
        v = random1
    elif random1 < -0.80 and random2 < -1.30 and random2 < random1:
        v = random2
    else:
        v = 0.0

    result_label.configure(text='Result: {:.2f}'.format(v))

font = 'georgia 20'

# Labels
number1_label = tk.Label(root, text='', font=font)
number1_label.pack()

number2_label = tk.Label(root, text='', font=font)
number2_label.pack()

result_label = tk.Label(root, text='Result:', font=font)
result_label.pack()

# Buttons
b = tk.Button(root, text='Next', width=6, height=1, 
    bg='white', fg='green', font=font, command=do_randoms)
b.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text='Result', width=5, height=1, 
    bg='white', fg='green', font=font, command=show_result)
b.pack()

# Initialize
do_randoms()

root.mainloop()
```

I've used globals to store the random numbers. It would be better to wrap the GUI in a class and to store the random numbers as attributes of the GUI class instance.

Comment: thanks, but now my second button which supposed to show the result isn't working ( you even deleted it in your code)

Comment: @MikayilAliyev I deleted it because I don't see why it's needed. In my version, each time the button is clicked a new pair of random numbers is generated, the result is calculated and all 3 values are displayed. Isn't that what you want? If my code doesn't do what you want please explain in your question exactly what you want the program to do.

Comment: This operation has to be calculated first and only then person should check whether he was right or not

Comment: @MikayilAliyev Do you mean that you want one button that when clicked shows the 2 new random numbers. And then when the Result button is clicked the result is displayed?

Comment: Yes, exactly: one button to calculate two random numbers result under showed conditions, and other to get two new random numbers